# Java program run in terminal, JDBC no suitable driver found

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to compile and run java program with JDBC in terminal. I typed:

```
javac -sourcepath src:lib -cp lib/postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar:lib/otherlibraries src/Database.java
```

Later I tried to run it:

```
java -cp src:lib/postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar:otherlibraries Database
```

But when i tried to find driver:

```
try
{ Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
{...}
```

I got the error that no suitable driver was found, but when i run program in NetBeans I could connect to database. Unfortunately, I have to do it by terminal. What I did wrong?

- Postgresql: 9.5.7
- Java: 1.8
- JDBC: postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4

Answer (score 0):

Check where the lib directory is.It should be in where your commands executed.

You can also do it whith absolute path

1.`cd ${rootPath}` *(The root directory of your project)*

2.`java -cp .:${absoluteLibPath}/lib/* Database` *(use `".:"` instead of `"src"`)*